# feof causing Segmentation fault (core dumped) error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, feof

I'm trying to make a function that gets a dynamically allocated string from a file, ignoring leading whitespace and going until it reached whitespace again, but I keep get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I tried using valgrind to find the cause and it says something about feof

```
Invalid read of size 4
==1155740==    at 0x48EDE24: feof (feof.c:35)
==1155740==    by 0x1095E7: my_string_extraction (my_string.c:73)
==1155740==    by 0x109285: main (main.c:10)
==1155740==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

However, when I copy it over to visual studio it works with no problems

**Function**

```
Status my_string_extraction(MY_STRING hMy_string, FILE* fp)
{
        char currCh;
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int wordStart = 0;
        struct My_string* temp = hMy_string;
        char* tempData;
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
                currCh = fgetc(fp);
                if ((currCh == ' ' || currCh == '\n' || currCh == '\t' || feof(fp)) && wordStart != 0)
                {
                        temp->data[i] = '\0';
                        temp->size = i - 1;
                        fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                        return SUCCESS;
                } else if (currCh == ' ' || currCh == '\n' || currCh == '\t') {
                } else {
                        if ((i+1) >= temp->cap)
                        {
                                tempData = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * temp->cap * 2);
                                for(x = 0; x < temp->size; x++)
                                {
                                        tempData[x] = temp->data[x];
                                }
                                free(temp->data);
                                temp->data = tempData;
                                temp->cap = temp->cap * 2;
                        }
                        wordStart = 1;
                        temp->data[i] = currCh;
                        i++;
                        temp->size = i;
                }
        }
        temp->data[i + 1] = '\0';
        return FAILURE;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_string.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        MY_STRING hMy_string = NULL;
        FILE* fp;
        hMy_string = my_string_init_default();
        fp = fopen("Spring2019/COMP1020/HANGMAN/simple.txt", "r");
        my_string_extraction(hMy_string, fp);

        my_string_destroy(&hMy_string);
        //fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check if `fopen` succeeded.  If it didn't, `fp` will be `NULL` and that would explain your segfault.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your present crash, but [using `feof` as the test to exit a loop is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: buffer overflow is another possible problem

Comment: You don't show your code for `struct My_string`. It's possible that's wrong.

Comment: The message is obvious. The `fp` is NULL. You do not check the results of any IO operations.  `fp = fopen("Spring2019/COMP1020/HANGMAN/simple.txt", "r"); if(!fp) {printf("File error\n"); exit(0);}` In this case fopen simply `failed`. Always check for errors. Usually 50 of programs is related to the error checks